# Implementing just TabLayout instead of full support:design in Android gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I started working in an Android application and realized that it implemented so many dependencies in the gradle file. I've been able to clean it a little bit and the weight and number of methods has decreased a lot. Good news!

Currently the only thing that worries me is this code line...

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

...because we only use one of its feature in one screen, TabLayout (it seems really necessary for the statistics screen).

Is there any way for implementing just this feature with gradle or proguard?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ProGuard, all unused code / resources will be stripped out automatically.

Google's libraries (e.g. `com.android.support:design`) have ProGuard configs that will do this when it is enabled.

Enabling it just requires the following in your app-level `build.gradle`, and running a release build:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
               'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

If you need further help setting up ProGuard, I suggest the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code).

Comment: Didn't know that the Google libraries made this automatic if the proguard is enabled. Thank you so much!